# Alterar a escrita de um input text através do JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Tenho um campo input que recebe a quantidade de produtos

```
 input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="5" id="pugQuant"  placeholder="0" onclick="calculo();"
```

E outro que mostra o total calculado. [total * valor]

```
 input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalPug" name=""  value="1500.00" 
 disabled
```

Estou querendo fazer o calculo com uma função e mostrar o valor no input
mas não sei como modificar com javascript. *Minha função retorna NaN*.

```
function calculo(){
    var pugQuant = document.getElementById("pugQuant").value;

    document.getElementById("totalPug").value = 1500.00 * pugQuant.id;
}
```

Comment: Por que você está utilizando esse .id na variável pugQuant ?

Comment: Na verdade eu vi em um site, mas retirei e deu certo kkk

Comment: Isso ai, amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver..

Recebe quantidade

```
 input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="5" id="pugQuant"  placeholder="0" onclick="calculo();"
```

Mostra Valor

```
input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalPug" name=""  value="1500.00" 
 disabled
```

Função errada....

Continha ".id" errado

```
function calculo(){
    var pugQuant = document.getElementById("pugQuant").value;

    document.getElementById("totalPug").value = 1500 * pugQuant.id;
}
```

Função correta...

```
function calculo(){
    var pugQuant = document.getElementById("pugQuant").value;

    document.getElementById("totalPug").value = 1500 * pugQuant;
}
```